# How to update console output instantly in an infinite loop on key press C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

I am trying to code the famous snake game, traditionally found on old school Nokia phones, I do have the head at the moment and simply working on changing its direction, and it does work, but only when I don't use the sleep function on the while loop.

This here will delay in updating the direction of the snake

```
while (true) {
    // some code to print the board here
    // logic to move on the board
    // logic to change direction
    sleep(1); // sleep one second to simulate snake moving on cell per second
    system("cls");    
}
```

This here will work fine

```
while (true) {
    // some code to print the board here
    // logic to move on the board
    // logic to change direction
    // no sleep function
    system("cls"); 
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const int BOARD_HEIGHT = 10;
const int BOARD_WIDTH  = 10;
char board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];

void clearScreen();
void createBoard();
void printBoard();
void move(int &, bool negative_direction);

int main() {

    createBoard();
    
    int x_pos = 4, y_pos = 4;
    int direction = 1;  
    char ch = '>';
    
    board[x_pos][y_pos] = ch;


    system("cls");  
    
    while (true) {
        
        printBoard();
        
        board[y_pos][x_pos] = '_';
        
        switch (direction) {
            case 0: // NORTH
                move(y_pos, true); // true: moving towards negative numbers
                break;
            case 1: // EAST
                move(x_pos, false); // false: moving towards positive numbers
                break;
            case 2: // SOUTH
                move(y_pos, false); 
                break;
            case 3: // WEST
                move(x_pos, true);
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Direction unknown..." << std::endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        // board[y_pos][x_pos] = ch;
        
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000 && direction != 2) {
            direction = 0;
            ch = '^';
        } 
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 0x8000 && direction != 3) {
            direction = 1;
            ch = '>';
        } 
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000 && direction != 0) {
            direction = 2;
            ch = 'v';
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 0x8000 && direction != 1) {
            direction = 3;
            ch = '<';
        }
        
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('X') & 0x8000)
            break;
        
        board[y_pos][x_pos] = ch;
        
        clearScreen();
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void clearScreen() {    
    COORD cursorPosition;
    cursorPosition.X = 0;   
    cursorPosition.Y = 0;   
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cursorPosition);
}

void createBoard() {
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_WIDTH; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_HEIGHT; col++) {
            board[row][col] = '_';
        }
    }
}

void move(int &dir, bool negative_direction) {
    if (negative_direction) 
         (dir == 0) ? dir = 9: dir--;
    else 
        (dir == 9) ? dir = 0: dir++;
}

void printBoard() {
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_WIDTH; row++) {
        // std::cout << std::setw(2) << (row + 1) << " ";
        for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_HEIGHT; col++) {
            std::cout << board[row][col] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

I used `GetAsyncKeyState()` instead of `GetKeyState()` thinking it would solve my problem, as I mentioned above, it changes direction well when I don't use the `sleep()` function, but I kinda have to use it so as to simulate one cell movement per second

Comment: You probably want to use some 3rd party lib like _ncurses_ to realize this. It's not possible using plain, OS independent c++ standard library functionality.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, let me go and learn about these ncurses :-) <3

Comment: Side note: Using `std::system` for clearing the screen [is generally not recommended](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/). See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen) from the official Microsoft documentation for better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the `Sleep` or `sleep` function together with `GetAsyncKeyState` is that you are only checking for keypresses while not sleeping, but you also want to be notified of keypresses that occur while sleeping.

Therefore, what you need is a function which will wait until either of the following events occur:

1. The user presses a key, or
2. a timeout occurs, which means that it is time to move the snake again.

The function [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) can do this.

Also, you should be using the function [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) instead of `GetAsyncKeyState`, because the function `GetAsyncKeyState` will only tell you whether a key is currently down<sup>1</sup>, whereas the function `ReadConsoleInput` uses an event queue which specifies whether a new keypress event has occurred.

Here is an example of a game loop you could use in your snake game:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

//the snake should move once per second, which is once
//every 1000 milliseconds
constexpr DWORD dwMillisecondsPerMove = 1000;

int game_loop()
{
    INPUT_RECORD ir;
    HANDLE hConInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD dwReadCount;
    DWORD dwStartTimeOfMove = GetTickCount();
    bool quit = false;

    enum class Direction { north, east, south, west };
    Direction snake_dir = Direction::east;
    const char *direction_strings[] = { "north", "east", "south", "west" };

    while ( !quit )
    {
        DWORD dwTimeRemaining = dwMillisecondsPerMove - ( GetTickCount() - dwStartTimeOfMove );

        switch ( WaitForSingleObject( hConInput, dwTimeRemaining ) )
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

            //there is a new input event, possibly a keyboard event

            //attempt to read input
            if ( !ReadConsoleInput( hConInput, &ir, 1, &dwReadCount ) || dwReadCount != 1 )
                throw std::runtime_error( "Unexpected input error!\n" );

            //only handle key-down events
            if ( ir.EventType != KEY_EVENT || !ir.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown )
                break;

            switch ( ir.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode )
            {
            case VK_UP:
                snake_dir = Direction::north;
                std::cout << "Changing snake direction to NORTH.\n";
                break;
            case VK_RIGHT:
                snake_dir = Direction::east;
                std::cout << "Changing snake direction to EAST.\n";
                break;
            case VK_DOWN:
                snake_dir = Direction::south;
                std::cout << "Changing snake direction to SOUTH.\n";
                break;
            case VK_LEFT:
                snake_dir = Direction::west;
                std::cout << "Changing snake direction to WEST.\n";
                break;
            case 0x51: //Q key
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
            break;

        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            std::cout << "Time to move the snake " << direction_strings[static_cast<int>(snake_dir)] << ".\n";
            dwStartTimeOfMove = GetTickCount();
            break;

        default:
            throw std::runtime_error( "unexpected error!" );
        }

        //make sure that the output buffer is flushed before
        //waiting again
        std::cout << std::flush;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        game_loop();
    }
    catch ( std::runtime_error &e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Time to move the snake east.
Time to move the snake east.
Changing snake direction to NORTH.
Time to move the snake north.
Time to move the snake north.
Time to move the snake north.
Changing snake direction to SOUTH.
Time to move the snake south.
Time to move the snake south.
Time to move the snake south.
Changing snake direction to WEST.
Time to move the snake west.
Time to move the snake west.
```

The output `"Changing snake direction to"` appears when I press an arrow key, and the other lines appear when the timeout expires, which is once per second.

To quit the program, you can press the <kbd>Q</kbd> key.

---

Footnote:

<sup>1</sup> One of the bits of the return value of the function `GetAsyncKeyState` actually does indicate whether a key has been pressed. However, according to the [official Microsoft documentation of that function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), this information is unreliable and is only provided for backward-compatibility, so it should not be used.

Comment: Hi @AndreasWenzel, thank you for your answer, I tried it, but I wasn't able to have it work with the code I have, but I will take another look over the weekend, I might have missed something as I am also busy with my fulltime work, but I will let you know how it goes. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

You need perform the cell movement once per second, but you do not need to delay for one second.  For example:

```
for(;;)
{
    // some code to print the board here
    // logic to move on the board
    // logic to change direction

    static clock_t tref = clock() ;
    clock_t now = clock() ;
    if( now - tref >= CLOCKS_PER_SEC )
    {
        // Every second update here
    }
    
    system("cls");    
}
```

You might want a WinAPI `Sleep(1)` - nominally 1 ms delay (note the case, not POSIX `sleep()`) in each iteration just to prevent the process hogging the CPU.

Comment: Your solution is using a [busy-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which is very wasteful of CPU resources. The problem can be solved in such a way that it consumes no CPU resources while waiting, by using [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject). See my answer for further information.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I covered that point in the last paragraph but did not include it in the code as it was not directly relevant to the question, but yes your answer has a probably lower CPU usage (though I doubt it is significant where the `Sleep()` is used), but is very Windows specific.  The style of the original code seemed rather more generic than that ( at least before the update).  I felt it useful to demonstrate this rather more portable construct, which is also a minimal change from the OP's existing code. Now they have a choice.

Comment: Another disadvantage of using `Sleep` is that if OP uses it together with `GetAsyncKeyState` (which OP is doing in their code), then OP might miss a keystroke while sleeping. However, the risk of this happening is there, even without using `Sleep`, because even a non-sleeping process is not guaranteed to be running all the time.

Comment: You are right that a busy-loop might be the appropriate choice in some situations. I am not the one who downvoted your answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel :  That is more a disadvantage `GetAsyncKeyState()` perhaps?   `GetAsyncKeyState` wouldn't be my choice - that part was in the _picture of code_ when I answered so I ignored it.  I would suggest `PeekConsoleInputEx()` with the `CONSOLE_READ_NOWAIT` flag wrapped in a suitable non-blocking `getKey()` function.  Also supports mouse and other input events so could be extended.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

Comment: Hi @Clifford, I appreciate your response, however, I don't understand the comment on the if condition, could you please take a look at my code since I have pasted all and get back to me, many thanks :-)

Comment: @C3lumusa: The comment `// Every second update here` means that whatever code you write at the location of that comment, it will be executed once per second.

Comment: @C3lumusa. The code does not wait or block, it simply polls the click to determine if it is time to do something.  That way everything outside the condition happens immediately, and what is inside happens once per second.  A shorter delay may still be advisable for CPU load.  The pattern applies regardless of your update, though as noted in the comment above, I wouldn't do keyboard input like that.